# Count occurency of SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I have a `MySQL` database with a `table` called "orders" containing all my orders. In this table I have different fields like:

```
id
userId  
dateOrder
```

I would like to get ALL the orders grouped by users ONLY for users who did `between 2 and 5` orders.

But my SQL queries don't work. Considering theses entries:

```
id  userId dateOrder  
1    138    2013-03-19  
2    138    2013-03-19
3    222    2013-03-19
```

I would like a SQL request that only select orders who have been made by users who did at least 2 orders.

For this example, the SQL should return :

```
userId 138
```

I tried with `GROUP BY`, with `DISTINCT`, but none of these works. Can you help me please ?
Thanks !!

Comment: Do you have examples of the queries that didn't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `HAVING` clause to get the result:

```
select userid
from orders
group by userid
having COUNT(*) >= 2
    and COUNT(*) <= 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11595/1)

If you then want to return all of the details about each order, you can expand the query to:

```
select o1.id, o1.userid, o1.dateorder
from orders o1
where exists (select userid
              from orders o2
              where o1.userid = o2.userid
              group by userid
              having COUNT(*) >= 2
                  and COUNT(*) <= 5)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11595/2)

Comment: any tips on how you created the Fiddle demo so quick

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it...

```
Select * from orders where userid in
(
Select userid from orders
group by userid having count(1) between 2 and 5
)
```

Comment: Thank you too. Nice and short solution.